# I got an error while running an Android Project

Tags: android-emulator

```
[2011-11-15 22:29:18 - MyAndroid] Failed to install MyAndroid.apk on device 'emulator-5554': device not found
[2011-11-15 22:29:18 - MyAndroid] com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: device not found
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a place where you paste an error and expect others to provide a magic bullet. To get sensible answers, you need to put in some effort - explain what you're trying to do, and where/what went wrong. It helps if you also explain what you've tried and what it didn't work. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

What troubleshooting steps have you done?

Has the app been installed on the emulator previously?  If so, fully uninstall the app from the emulator first.

Try closing the emulator, and eclipse (if using eclipse). Then restart and try again.

If the issue keeps happening, you may need to delete the 'cache.img' in your AVD directory.

And if that doesn't help, delete the AVD, and recreate it.